# Set border color for FloatingActionButton in support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button

In support library [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) is introduced. There is an option to set border width for button with `app:borderWidth="2dp"`, but how about setting border color?

I create a custom drawable for that porpuse, such as:

```
<item>
     <shape android:shape="oval">
         <solid android:color="@color/color1" />
         <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />
     </shape>
</item>
```

and try both `android:background` and `app:backgroundTint` properties of FloatingActionButton to set background. Non of them worked. Note that app:backgroundTint seems just to accept color and not drawable

Anyone know any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `android:src` attribute?
Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"
    andriod:scaleType="center"  /> <!-- You need to scale your src. ->
```

I hope it will work.

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_icon" /> <!-- include your icon here -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval"> <!-- or rectangle -->

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can add your icon in `drawable` shape `xml`. And add a border to your icon and apply it to `FAB`.

I added a `hdpi`  icon in my shape file and this is the result I got.

And the actual drawable size should be **24dp** according to the Google design specs.

[image]

Comment: No, that just set drawable in the center of FloatingActionButton. for that purpose I have an icon. I am looking for a solution for FloatingActionButton on its own.

Comment: Should I use this drawable for which property? ( src, background, backgroundTint)

Comment: Have you tried it once yourself? or you just guess that it should be a solution? If yes please share your source code in a simple example which confirm your proposal.

Comment: As I told you android:src just centralize the icon. I guess you did not properly understood what I am asking.

Comment: You really made me implement the fab. Anyways I edited my answer. You need to scale the fab. `scaleType` should be center. And I tried `hdpi` icon. Try resizing your icon. And then again tell me, is it centralizing the icon?